# MySQL query - get column values "greater than..."

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$score = 10;
SELECT timecode, count(tag) as n_tags, tag
FROM dados
WHERE dados.tag = 'tag1' 
AND dados.filename = 'file.mp4'
AND (timecode >= '-5' AND timecode <= '15')
AND (timecode = '$score')
GROUP BY timecode
ORDER BY count(tag) DESC
```

However I want to change the 6 line to:

```
AND (timecode = '$score' AND n_tags > 3)
```

but it doesn't seems the correct way to do, it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You are both checking equality `timecode = '$score'` and checking if it is in a range `timecode >= -5 AND timecode <= 15`.  Is `$score` inside that range? (so why do you need the range at all?)

Comment: Test that $score is between -5 and 15 before making your db query, and only execute the query if it is - then you can eliminate AND (timecode >= '-5' AND timecode <= '15')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that line from your WHERE clause and put in a HAVING clause.  A HAVING clause will look at aggregate results. WHERE does not.

```
SELECT timecode, count(tag) as n_tags, tag
FROM dados
WHERE dados.tag = 'tag1' 
AND dados.filename = 'file.mp4'
AND (timecode >= '-5' AND timecode <= '15')
AND (timecode = '$score')
GROUP BY timecode
HAVING count(tag) > 3
ORDER BY count(tag) DESC
```

This line is redundant and could be dropped:     AND (timecode >= '-5' AND timecode <= '15')

```
SELECT timecode, count(tag) as n_tags, tag
FROM dados
WHERE dados.tag = 'tag1' 
AND dados.filename = 'file.mp4'
AND (timecode = '$score')
GROUP BY timecode
HAVING count(tag) > 3
ORDER BY count(tag) DESC
```

Comment: A HAVING clause will look at aggregate results.  WHERE does not.

Comment: @Tom The point is that your answer needs to include that information. A solution without an explanation isn't really an answer - it's just, well, a solution.

Comment: `n_tags` is an alias of an aggregated column. do you think alias define on the same level can be used on having clause?

Comment: Yes, the alias can be used in the HAVING clause.  I generally don't do it that way but it can.

Comment: @Tom Correct. I just tested it. (*I don't know why this works on mysql*) In other RDBMS you can't.

Comment: @JW - Yeah I know.  You can do a lot of things in MySQL you can't do in other RDBMS.  Some times that's good, some time that's bad.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use aggregated fields in a WHERE clause. `count()` results are only available after ALL applicable rows have been considered. But the `where` filtering is done as each individual row is parsed. Cliche statement, but you're trying to count your chickens before they've hatched.

Such things have to be done with a `HAVING` clause, which is basically exactly the same as a `where`, but is applied just before the final results are sent back to the client. So...

```
SELECT ..., count(tag) as n_tags
...
WHERE (timecode = '$score')

HAVING (n_tags > 3)
```